# Where did the moon based interceptors launch from in the UFO TV series?

Tags: gerry-anderson, ufo

In the UFO TV series, the pilots of the moon based interceptors are always shown entering a slide   which presumably takes them from one of the habitation spheres directly to their ships.  The ships are then raised from an under-moon storage area to a series of side-by-side craters in order to be launched.

[image]

[image]

But in all aerial images of the moonbase itself, there is no indication that these launch silos are anywhere near the moon base.  And the base itself is never alluded to be anything bigger than what is shown.

[image]

So where are these silos located in relation to the moon base?

After recently watching all 26 episodes this aspect just never made sense to me (and no, that is not the only things that doesn't make sense in-universe)

Comment: It's been decades since I watched the series, but you've reminded me that I own a set of the DVDs.  But It looks like the launch pads are in craters, so the elevators must lead up to one of the nearby craters.  Maybe the moonbase is more expansive underground.

Comment: @LAK The craters that the interceptors use are never in any shots of the base.  One possible reason *is* that the moon base far more extensive than ever shown.  But Gerry Anderson was never one to shy away from showing dramatic scenery in any of his other shows.  Look at how much footage he got from the Thunderbirds when simply traveling from Jeff Tracy's office to TB 1, 2 or 3.  In UFO there was never anything shown between pilots sliding down the shoot and teh interceptors getting ready to take off

Answer (score 3):

There is a [guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Juc7lo_pWD4&t=429s) and it tells us that silos are actually should not be seen (I made screenshoots from the video for convenience):

[image]

> **Disguising the silo doors as craters** offers several advantages when
> launching the interceptors - most obviously camouflage - and the high
> walls offer some cover if the interceptors are beeing launched while
> the base is under attack.

[image]

> ...**subterranean** silos and equipment storage bays build on a scale
> unseen before (metaphorically and literally) when compared  to other
> lunar programmes. ...The extent of Moonbases's facility allows the
> bases's **interceptors** and ground vehicles to undergo maintanance and
> refit in a safe, pressurized atmosphere.

What we also have is some fanart (it allows us to evaluate the distance to the silos:
[image]
https://www.facebook.com/photo?fbid=474387014699331&set=a.356962546441779

And some toys:
[image]
http://megomuseum.com/community/showthread.php?112207-UFO-Eagle

Bay itself (as seen on the [video guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Juc7lo_pWD4&t=440s)):
[image]